# creating the current state of a css button

Tags: css, button

Guys i am trying and failing to make a current view state on my css buttons......the sprite has two states, an off and over state..i want to have the over state also be the current state on the page being viewed....here is the css for the button as well as the html:

css:

```
.inbox {
    border: none;
    width: 88px;
    height: 26px;`enter code here`
    background: url(images/v2images/default_inbox_BTN.png) no-repeat top left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.inbox:hover {
        background-position: -88px 0;
}
```

html:

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="inbox" />
```

I assumed that i would just create a current state (.inbox:current) and just adjust the positioning to match that of the over state, not unlike hover but without the negative value, but it didnt work.

thanks in advance dudes

Comment: What do you mean by "current view state?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  You would have a class.  `:hover` is a pseudo-class.  You can't really "force" that hover.  What you can do, though, is add a class, such as:

```
.inbox:hover
, .inbox.current
{
        background-position: -88px 0;
}
```

and

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="inbox current">
```

So now your CSS says *for the class inbox, when hovered, set the bg position.  But also, when the class inbox is also found on an element with the class current, apply the same bg position rules*

If you wanted to use a single class, you could do

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="inbox inbox-current">
```

then your CSS

```
.inbox:hover
, .inbox-current
{
        background-position: -88px 0;
}
```

Same results but more support for older browsers

Answer (score 1):

there is no real current state in CSS, you have to manually set it your self with either javascript (jquery) or set it when you load the page. ie. have the class inbox and the class current as two seperate classes, and have

```
.current { background-position: -88px 0 !important; }
```

and detect click on inbox, remove current from all other buttons, and add it to inbox.

Comment: ugh was hoping it could be sans javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can always expand the ruleset:

```
.inbox:hover, .current {
    background-position: -88px 0;
}
```

Then if `.inbox` is either being hovered *or* has the `.current` class, it will appear in the hovered state.  You could also use `:focus` and `:active`